# For VRChat specifically. I have the head from one model and the body from another. Character is floating in unity when scene is played

Tags: modeling, armature, bones

I used the body from one model and the head from another. I manually placed them together as well as I could and it looks fine. I kept the bones for the respective models, deleted the ones I didn't need and merged the armature and re-parented the bones. I had a feeling it would be more complicated than this, but I figured I could just merge the two armatures and it'd be fine, but in Unity when I play the scene out, the character while in the T-pose just slowly floats away. I think the important part is the T-pose, because no animations are playing when the idle animation should be.

Is this problem too complicated or is there a fix?